# Changing the Everyone group on a printer?

Tags: permissions, printing, printer

We have new printers coming into our office next month.
I've managed to create a couple of scripts that will install the printer or printer driver for everyone. The trouble is we need to set the "everyone" group on the printer to have "Manage this printer" and "Manage documents" as permissions.

Any idea on how to achieve this using scripts or some other method so I can remotely push it out to every user?

Comment: I have not done this before, but there are utilities from MS for modifying permissions on objects, and a quick Google seems to indicate that includes printers. https://www.google.com/search?q=icacls+for+printers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can edit the 'everyone' group (I believe you can) - you just need to edit it on the server hosting the printer.

On that server, go to devices -> select the printer, properties and then you can find the everyone group and edit it's permissions.

Comment: Unfortunatly our printers are installed locally for each user/computer.

Comment: Everyone is a default group in both local permissions and in AD.